# Convert json to dataframe using Apache Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm learning Apache Spark after having not used it for quite a while and attempting to convert this MongoDB string :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "601de7179acebcfb50c8f347"
    },
    "timestamp": {
        "$numberLong": "1612572439411"
    },
    "newsdata": {
        "test1": ["n1", "n2"],
        "test2": ["n3", "n4"]
    }
}
```

to a Spark dataframe using :

```
package sparkanalysis

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object WordCount {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val mongoString = "{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"601de7179acebcfb50c8f347\"}," +
      "\"timestamp\":{\"$numberLong\":\"1612572439411\"}," +
      "\"newsdata\":{" +
      "\"test1\" : [\"n1\",\"n2\"]" +
      ",\"test2\" : [\"n3\",\"n4\"]}}"

    print(mongoString)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
      .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
      .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val df = spark.read.json(mongoString)

    println(df)

  }

}
```

But I receive exception :

```
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: {"_id":%7B%22$oid%22:%22601de7179acebcfb50c8f347%22%7D,%22timestamp%22:%7B%22$numberLong%22:%221612572439411%22%7D,%22newsdata%22:%7B%22test1%22%20:%20%5B%22n1%22,%22n2%22%5D,%22test2%22%20:%20%5B%22n3%22,%22n4%22%5D%7D%7D
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1(DataSource.scala:546)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:391)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at sparkanalysis.WordCount$.main(WordCount.scala:24)
    at sparkanalysis.WordCount.main(WordCount.scala)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: {"_id":%7B%22$oid%22:%22601de7179acebcfb50c8f347%22%7D,%22timestamp%22:%7B%22$numberLong%22:%221612572439411%22%7D,%22newsdata%22:%7B%22test1%22%20:%20%5B%22n1%22,%22n2%22%5D,%22test2%22%20:%20%5B%22n3%22,%22n4%22%5D%7D%7D
    at java.base/java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1940)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:203)
    ... 15 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've verified using https://jsonlint.com/ that the JSON is valid. Do I need to specify a case class in order to convert to dataframe correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass JSON string directly to `.read.json`, it accepts only path to json file as `String` or entire dataset `Dataset<String>`. You can try to load it to dataframe as below:

```
val ds = Seq(mongoString).toDS
val df = spark.read.json(ds)
```

.

```
scala> df.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+
|                 _id|            newsdata|      timestamp|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+
|[601de7179acebcfb...|[[n1, n2], [n3, n4]]|[1612572439411]|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+
```